# Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip, visualisation

[image]

I tried to visualize the imagery but it told me there were no bands to visualize, what might be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please share (as text, not picture) the first lines of your script which shows what `Kitui` is?

Comment: No bands to visualize no images for that dates range. Probably you are using 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED' product  where dataset availability is only for
2017-03-28T00:00:00Z–2023-07-11T13:10:20; not for '2002-01-01','2002-12-31' as it can be observed in above picture.

Answer (score 1):

You need to share your code as follows. In it there are two different date ranges: yours and one where there are images.

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(37.9988, -1.3799); //Kitui, Kenya

Map.centerObject(pt, 9);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED').filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 25))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(pt));
  
var filtered1 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.date('2002-01-01','2002-12-31'));

print(filtered1);

var filtered2 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01','2020-12-31'));

print(filtered2);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,"bands":["B4","B3","B2"],"min":350,"max":2379,"gamma":1};

Map.addLayer(filtered2.median().select('B4', 'B3','B2'), imageVisParam, 'image');
Map.addLayer(pt, {}, 'point');
```

Above lines produce following result for the first image of filtered2:

[image]